# OnClick on TextView

Tags: android

I have a lot of TextView and I have to make sure that after having clicked on to open another layout. I tried to do it this way:

```
public void lunedi1(final View sfNormal) {
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    TextView info;
    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    info.setText(info1[0]);
}
```

He opens another layout but I get an error on the variable "info1": info1 cannot be resolved to a variable.
What should I do? I need to initialize a second activity?

Comment: where did you initialize `info1` ?

Comment: in public void getData()

Comment: is `info1` is a field of the class?

Comment: plz edit question an show where info1 is?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it to the second `Activity`, so you won't need to declare it again. You can do that using `Intent`s, this way:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MyFirstActivity.this, YourSecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("info1", info1);
startActivity(intent);
```

Once you're on your second `Activity`, you'll get your extras by:

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
final String[] info1 = intent.getStringArrayExtra("info1");
```

Comment: i use this:    lunedi1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
             @Override  
             public void onClick(View v) {  
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
              final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
              intent.putExtra("info1", info1);
              startActivity(intent); 
                 
             }  
         });